# how to stop an Interval function in my jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wrote a  jquery plugin to make a div auto scroll,i used function setInterval to make the div stop for a while and then keeps on scroll. 
here is the code

```
(function($){
"use strict";
function scrolltotop(obj,height,speed){
var ch=parseInt($(obj).css("margin-top"))+29;
    $(obj).parent().find(".moving").remove();
    $(obj).after($(obj).clone().addClass("copy"));
    $(obj).addClass("moving").removeClass("copy").animate({
        "margin-top":-27
    },speed);
    loop=setInterval(function(){
        ch+=27;
        if(ch < height+27){
            $(obj).animate({
                "margin-top":-ch
            },speed,function(){
            loop;
            })      
        }else{
            clearInterval(loop);
            scrolltotop($(obj).next(".copy"),height,speed); 
        }
    },4000)
}               
$.fn.extend({ 
    autoscroll: function(options) {  
        var defaults = {  
            speed: 1000,  
            scroller : '#scroller',  
            scroller_container : '#scroller_container'  
        }    
        var options =  $.extend(defaults, options); 
        var height=$(options.scroller).height();
        var stop=stopscroll();
        //console.log(height)

        scrolltotop(options.scroller,height,options.speed);
    }, 
});  
}(jQuery));
$("#list2").autoscroll({scroller:"#list2",scroller_container:"#container_2"});
```

it works well,but idont know how to make the div stop scroll after i init the plugin.

Comment: Where do you define height in your plugin? I think your loop keeps on looping because you never get to the else statement because your height is probably undefined. Try outputting it to the console.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand the problem you want to move the div scroll line by line waiting 4s until you reach the end.

I simplified your scrolltotop function

```
function scrolltotop(obj,height,speed){

    var ch = 0;        
    var loop = setInterval(function(){  

        ch+=27;
        $('#container_2').animate({
            scrollTop: ch
        }, speed);

        if(ch >= height){
            console.log('Out of loop');    
            clearInterval(loop);
        }

    },4000);    
}
```

You can see a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/jCw3y/
May be you can adapt my code to use it in your plugin.

(You're using "use strict". Remember to declare javascript variables always. var loop, var ch e.t.c)

To stop manually you can save the intervalId and call clearInterval when you want.
Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ccR4t/

And finally, another example with pure jquery. Using animate and stop functions to control all.

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    function scrolltotop($container, options) {
        $container.animate({
            scrollTop: options.scrollerHeight
        }, options.speed, function () {
            console.log('Animation completed');
        });
    }

    $.fn.extend({
        autoscroll: function (options) {

            var $me = this;
            var defaults = {
                speed: 1000,
                scroller_container: '#scroller_container',
                scroller: '#list2'
            }
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            options.scrollerHeight = $(options.scroller).height();

            scrolltotop($me, options);
        },
    });
}(jQuery));

$("#container_2").autoscroll({
    scroller: '#list2',
    speed: 10000
});

// stop scroll after 4 sec
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#container_2').stop();
    alert('scroll manually stopped')
}, 4000);
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/c8Ns8/

Comment: in my sample ,the div can scroll without gap, but i can`t stop it when i need, i want to stop scroll manually by use a function but not stop it automatically, i am really confused, please tell how to handle, i am really new in writing jquery plugin,thank you